# How to play with friends that only have the original Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I have Diablo III: Reaper of Souls. My friends only have vanilla Diablo III. How can I play with them (on PS3)?

Comment: Not sure how it works on consoles, but on PC the person not having the expansion needs to open the game and then the person with the expansion can join in. They stop leveling at 60 though, while you continue your path to 70.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you cannot simply because of different versions.  [Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14278978502)

Scroll down to bottom of the replies, blizzard employee explains.